# Missing College Scorecard data for Navy, Army, Air Force

Tags: education, collegescorecard

I'm using the College Scorecard api to pull data for various schools. It seems that data for Army, Navy, and the U.S Air Force is not available. I tried querying the API using REGIONS = 0 (U.S. Service Schools) and I also tried searching by school name, but the only data I could find was for the Marines. Will this data be available any time soon?

Comment: What school do marines attend? I wasn't aware there was a service academy for marines. West Point, USMA, and Army don't return in name search, and Navy doesn't return in total results for all of Maryland. These advanced search options are...odd. Very limited, and yet no choice for military school.....

Comment: United States Merchant Marine Academy. The Coast Guard is also missing. I went directly to IPEDS and pulled the data and all the schools mentioned have a region = 0, but none of them except the Marines is available via the API.

Comment: Towson University is also missing from the dataset. How come? I know for a fact Towson is a title IV school.

Comment: @JennaAllen This is not correct. The Merchant Marines are something different entirely and fall under the Dept of Transportation. The USMC falls under the Department of the Navy and so Marines attend the Naval Academy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

College Scorecard data are currently limited to institutions that participate in Title-IV federal financial aid programs.  As the U.S. service academies do not participate in Title-IV, the data needed for inclusion in Scorecard are unavailable.